# RabbitMQ maximum TTL value

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm writing a rabbit adapter for a messaging framework that we have, which accepts a DateTime ExpiryTimestampUtc for a message

It's not documented what the maximum message TTL value is, just that:

> The value of the TTL argument or policy must be a non-negative integer (0 <= n), describing the TTL period in milliseconds. Thus a value of 1000 means that a message added to the queue will live in the queue for 1 second or until it is delivered to a consumer. The argument can be of AMQP 0-9-1 type short-short-int, short-int, long-int, or long-long-int.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

In our code, we send a Expiry Timestamp of 9999-12-31 23:59:59:999 if the message is essentially never meant to expire. We handle this in the adapter by:

```
 properties.Expiration = ((long)(message.ExpiryTimestampUtc - _clock.UtcNow).TotalMilliseconds).ToString();
```

This crashes when publishing the message to rabbit

```
Already closed: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text='PRECONDITION_FAILED - invalid expiration '251733866845480': {value_too_large,251733866845480}', classId=60, methodId=40
```

By trial and error, it seems that the maximum TTL is around 288094644805 milliseconds - which puts it at around 3334 days (~ end of 2031 at time of writing). This appears to be a rolling value, so the maximum expiry date today is earlier than the maximum expiry date in a week.

This comment from 2015:

> The limit used to be 4294967295 (2^32-1) milliseconds, so about 49 days.
> We have eliminated it in recent releases. The limit now is likely high enough to
> not matter in most cases :)

https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/cvvkB0rOAdU

still didn't answer the question.

**Does anyone know the answer for sure?**

I'm thinking that (although it introduces inconsistent behaviour in our framework) that if expiry timestamp > 288094644805 then don't set an expiration. Technically it's wrong but tbh, by then the message is going to be stale anyway ;)